# Repeatedly write to stdin and read from stdout of a process from python

Tags: python

I have a piece of fortran code that reads some numbers from STDIN and writes results to STDOUT. For example:

```
do
  read (*,*) x
  y = x*x
  write (*,*) y
enddo
```

So I can start the program from a shell and get the following sequence of *inputs*/**outputs**:

*5.0*
**25.0**
*2.5*
**6.25**

Now I need to do this from within python. After futilely wrestling with subprocess.Popen and looking through old questions on this site, I decided to use pexpect.spawn:

```
import pexpect, os
p = pexpect.spawn('squarer')
p.setecho(False)
p.write("2.5" + os.linesep)
res = p.readline()
```

and it works. The problem is, the **real** data I need to pass between python and my fortran program is an array of 100,000 (or more) double precision floats. If they're contained in an array called `x`, then

```
p.write(' '.join(["%.10f"%k for k in x]) + os.linesep)
```

times out with the following error message from pexpect:

```
buffer (last 100 chars):   
before (last 100 chars):   
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>  
match: None  
match_index: None  
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 8574
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

unless `x` has less than 303 elements. Is there a way to pass large amounts of data to/from STDIN/STDOUT of another program?

I have tried splitting the data into smaller chunks, but then I lose a **lot** in speed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an issue of inter-process (pipe) buffering. Please check my answer.

Comment: i had exactly this problem.  thanks for the write-up.

Answer (score 6):

Found a solution using the subprocess module, so I'm posting it here for reference if anyone needs to do the same thing.

```
import subprocess as sbp

class ExternalProg:

    def __init__(self, arg_list):
        self.opt = sbp.Popen(arg_list, stdin=sbp.PIPE, stdout=sbp.PIPE, shell=True, close_fds=True)

    def toString(self,x):
        return ' '.join(["%.12f"%k for k in x])

    def toFloat(self,x):
        return float64(x.strip().split())

    def sendString(self,string):
        if not string.endswith('\n'):
            string = string + '\n'
        self.opt.stdin.write(string)

    def sendArray(self,x):
        self.opt.stdin.write(self.toString(x)+'\n')

    def readInt(self):
        return int(self.opt.stdout.readline().strip())

    def sendScalar(self,x):
        if type(x) == int:
            self.opt.stdin.write("%i\n"%x)
        elif type(x) == float:
            self.opt.stdin.write("%.12f\n"%x)

    def readArray(self):
        return self.toFloat(self.opt.stdout.readline())

    def close(self):
        self.opt.kill()
```

The class is invoked with an external program called 'optimizer' as:

```
optim = ExternalProg(['./optimizer'])
optim.sendScalar(500) # send the optimizer the length of the state vector, for example
optim.sendArray(init_x) # the initial guess for x
optim.sendArray(init_g) # the initial gradient g
next_x = optim.readArray() # get the next estimate of x
next_g = evaluateGradient(next_x) # calculate gradient at next_x from within python
# repeat until convergence
```

On the fortran side (the program compiled to give the executable 'optimizer'), a 500-element vector would be read in so:

```
read(*,*) input_vector(1:500)
```

and would be written out so:

```
write(*,'(500f18.11)') output_vector(1:500)
```

and that's it! I've tested it with state vectors up to 200,000 elements (which is the upper limit of what I need right now). Hope this helps someone other than myself. This solution works with ifort and xlf90, but not with gfortran for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: You say you found a solution using "communicate" but you didn't use it anywhere in your code. What you wrote down worked for me though thanks!

Answer (score 2):

example squarer.py program (it just happens to be in Python, use your Fortran executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
data= sys.stdin.readline() # expecting lots of data in one line
processed_data= data[-2::-1] # reverse without the newline
sys.stdout.write(processed_data+'\n')
```

example target.py program:

```
import thread, Queue
import subprocess as sbp

class Companion(object):
    "A companion process manager"
    def __init__(self, cmdline):
        "Start the companion process"
        self.companion= sbp.Popen(
            cmdline, shell=False,
            stdin=sbp.PIPE,
            stdout=sbp.PIPE)
        self.putque= Queue.Queue()
        self.getque= Queue.Queue()
        thread.start_new_thread(self._sender, (self.putque,))
        thread.start_new_thread(self._receiver, (self.getque,))

    def _sender(self, que):
        "Actually sends the data to the companion process"
        while 1:
            datum= que.get()
            if datum is Ellipsis:
                break
            self.companion.stdin.write(datum)
            if not datum.endswith('\n'):
                self.companion.stdin.write('\n')

    def _receiver(self, que):
        "Actually receives data from the companion process"
        while 1:
            datum= self.companion.stdout.readline()
            que.put(datum)

    def close(self):
        self.putque.put(Ellipsis)

    def send(self, data):
        "Schedule a long line to be sent to the companion process"
        self.putque.put(data)

    def recv(self):
        "Get a long line of output from the companion process"
        return self.getque.get()

def main():
    my_data= '12345678 ' * 5000
    my_companion= Companion(("/usr/bin/python", "squarer.py"))

    my_companion.send(my_data)
    my_answer= my_companion.recv()
    print my_answer[:20] # don't print the long stuff
    # rinse, repeat

    my_companion.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `main` function contains the code you will use: setup a `Companion` object, `companion.send` a long line of data, `companion.recv` a line. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Hi ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, thanks for the suggestion. But it does not work :-( I copied and pasted your code into two files squarer.py and target.py. But when I do "python target.py" I get an interminable wait period where nothing happens. So I executed "%run target.py" from the ipython shell, then hit Ctrl+C to interrupt the wait, and got the following traceback:

     32 def recv(self):
---> 33   return self.getque.get()

/usr/lib/python2.6/Queue.pyc in get(self, block, timeout)

--> 168   self.not_empty.wait()

/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc in wait(self, timeout)
--> 239   waiter.acquire()

Help!

Comment: Can I have somewhere one of these very long lines (perhaps in [bpaste](http://bpaste.net/) or some other paste bin) so that I can approximate your conditions? This code runs for me…

Comment: I just compared the code here with my code, and there was an indentation error here in the line `if not datum.endswith`. Can you please try again with the current version of the code?

Comment: I just corrected the indentation error, and your code runs for me now (even with a 500,000 character my_data). I will implement this in my actual code now and see if it still works :-)

Comment: Hi ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, in my actual application the recv() call gets stuck indefinitely. My fortran application writes an integer with "write(*,*) i", but this for some reason never reaches python :-( Is there a way I can send you the fortran code I'm using?

Comment: @TM5: Python tries to read a *line*, so whatever Fortran sends, should end with a newline. Does your Fortran program end its data with a newline?

Comment: I believe so. I wrote a simple fortran program with two lines:

orig_array = (/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
write(*,*) orig_array(1:5)

When I open this fortran program using your Companion class:

prog = Companion(('myfprog'))
prog.recv()

I get numbers 1 to 5 plus a newline in python. So Fortran's 'write(*,*)' does write a newline at the end. This is exactly what I use in my real Fortran program. Is there a way I could attach some files here to show you a slightly more complicated example that does not work?

Comment: In the previous comment, I meant 'write(asterisk,asterisk)', but somehow the asterisks got converted into null characters.

Comment: I pasted a simple fortran program and the corresponding python caller at http://bpaste.net/show/11256/. Could you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't have `gfortran`, I have `ifort` installed, and it seems that `ifort` splits its output with newlines, so when I send it 5 numbers, it sends back *two* lines, one with three numbers, the other with two numbers. Also, you don't need to send `'\r\n'` at the end, just `'\n'`, but my code already does that for you in `_sender`. Is it possible that you too get the `squarer` output as multiple lines? You should make sure you read more lines until you have as many numbers as you sent. Also, why run through ipython and not just add a `main()` at the end of target.py and run it normally?

Comment: No, gfortran spits out a single line. In general, gfortran doesn't split its output across multiple lines. I don't think this is the problem, since the first recv() gets stuck. But does this example work when you use ifort instead of gfortran? I added '\r\n' just to see if it makes a difference, but it didn't. The problem remains with and without '\r\n'. And lastly, running it directly by adding a main() at the end didn't solve the problem :-(

Comment: @TM5: it runs. The ifort executable spews out an error when EOF is reached (ie there are no more data), but otherwise it runs.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: I don't have ifort, so I tested it with xlf90 (IBM's compiler). It works! Also, xlf90 doesn't split the output over multiple lines, which is excellent. But now I'm confused; why should the same fortran code -- quite a simple one at that -- produce different results with xlf90 and gfortran? Do you know of any way to make this compiler-independent?

Comment: Also, the close() method on Companion doesn't kill the 'squarer' process. When I exit python (which is after calling the close() method), I get the following message: '"squarer.F90", line 6: 1525-001 The READ statement on the file (standard input) cannot be completed because the end of the file was reached.  The program will stop.' Is there any way that I could terminate the spawned process (without exiting python) and thus not end up with zombie processes?

Comment: If the parent process ends, there should be no “zombie” processes left (and anyway, “zombie” processes aren't really processes, just an entry in the process table). Anyway, after the `while 1` loop in `_sender` you can do a `self.companion.stdin.close()`; you shouldn't have to kill the subprocess, rather make it understand EOF and exit gracefully.

Comment: Just verified that this works with ifort as well. So now I need to switch my compilers!

Comment: Hi ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, I'm afraid my actual application still has problems. Up to about 100 floating point numbers, the transfer from fortran to python works. Beyond that, python gets nothing. Could you please have a look at the code at http://oron.com/j7p6rdx47y9s/python_pipe.tgz.html ? The fortran code is, as I mentioned before, an optimizer (execute the script "make"). If you set N=100 in the python code (100-element state vector) and run test_optim.py, then the transfer of data works. But even for N=1000 it doesn't, and I actually need N=50000 or more (the fortran code can handle it) :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a huge simplification: Break your Python into two things.

```
python source.py | squarer | python sink.py
```

The `squarer` application is  your Fortran code.  Reads from stdin, writes to stdout.

Your `source.py` is your Python that does

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(' '.join(["%.10f"%k for k in x]) + os.linesep)
```

Or, perhaps something a tiny bit simpler, i.e.

```
from __future__ import print_function
print( ' '.join(["{0:.10f}".format(k) for k in x]) )
```

And your `sink.py` is something like this.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    # process the line
```

Separating source, squarer and sink gets you 3 separate processes (instead of 2) and will use more cores.  More cores == more concurrency == more fun.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. But won't work for me, because for my application `squarer` is actually an optimizer that reads a state vector (many variables) and suggests a new one. The python script feeds the optimizer the current vector, accepts the new one, does some simulations with it, and re-feeds the optimizer the results of this simulation. So `source.py` and `sink.py` for me would be the same script, and would need to know each other's variables and so on.

Comment: @TM5: Does this loop indefinitely?  Is there an upper bound on how many times this can run?  What's the original source for the data, separate from the results of a simulation?  You're initial requirements don't reflect any of this complexity.

Comment: No, it does not loop indefinitely, but the exit condition can be determined either by python or fortran. For the moment, let's assume that fortran determines the termination condition. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "original source of the data". Basically, the steps are as follows: (1) python performs simulation on x0, calculates f'(x0), feeds it to fortran, (2) fortran suggests a new x1 based on x0 and f'(x0), feeds it to python, (3) go back to step 1 with x0 replaced by x1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only add one linebreak here:

```
p.write(' '.join(["%.10f"%k for k in x]) + os.linesep)
```

instead of adding one per line.

Comment: Yes, I only add one linebreak at the end, because the *real* fortran code looks like:

    `read (*,*) x(1:n_state)`

where `n_state` is set to (say) 100,000. But I've also seen that as far as the `read` statement goes, it doesn't make a difference whether I add linebreaks between numbers or not.

P.S. - Why don't the formatting rules in the original post not work for comments? For example, for this comment I couldn't indent by four spaces to signify a piece of code. Nor could I make a separate paragraph for this "P.S."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're timing out (default timeout, I believe, 30 seconds) because preparing, sending, receiving, and processing that much data is taking a lot of time.  Per [the docs](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect), `timeout=` is an optional named parameter to the `expect` method, which you're not calling -- maybe there's an undocumented way to set the default timeout in the initializer, which could be found by poring over the sources (or, worst case, created by hacking those sources).

If the Fortran program read and saved (say) 100 items at a time, with a prompt, syncing up would become enormously easier.  Could you modify your Fortran code for the purpose, or would you rather go for the undocumented / hack approach?

Comment: I doubt that reading and writing the data is taking too much time. When I have 303 numbers, the transfer from python to fortran takes less than a second (I timed it). When I have 304 numbers, it times out after 30 seconds.

AFAIK, this magic number `303` depends on the number of digits I write per number, so I think it's a question of number of bytes.

Comment: @TM5, looks like some buffer is filling up and not being properly flushed/read (at least not within the 30 seconds' timeout). Changing the Fortran code to accept 100 numbers at a time rather than needed them all in one big gulp, as I suggested in the 2nd paragraph, sounds more and more like the simplest solution; and you're not telling us whether it's feasible in your case.

Comment: my real state vector contains 10,000 elements (typically), and it varies from run to run. So yes, it's possible to modify the fortran and python applications to break up the I/O into chunks, but then I have to pass an "end-of-data" signal, and it's not very elegant. I'd like to find a more elegant approach. Is there no other way to set up an inter-process communication?