# Start process and reuse with PID in python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, executable

My main process/thread starts an executable that starts waiting for a signal after echoing `Algorithm loaded`. I am using the `subprocess.Popen` class for running the executable.
Later, a thread is started that is supposed to send a signal to the earlier started executable. But I have no clue of how to send a signal to that particular subprocess from that thread.
Is it possible to pass `PID`'s and *"recover"* subprocesses using the `PID`? The purpose of reusing the process is to send something equivalent to `stdin`.

Here's my code for starting the executable:

```
def start_module():
    cmd = '%s/libraries/OpenBR' % settings.MODULES_DIR
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if line.find('Algorithm loaded') > -1:
            break

    return 0
```

Answer (score 4):

The `process` variable in your code refers to a `Popen` object, which supports a `pid` attribute.  If you have your `start_module` function return the process, you can later send it a signal using `os.kill`.  For example:

```
def start_module():
    cmd = '%s/libraries/OpenBR' % settings.MODULES_DIR
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if line.find('Algorithm loaded') > -1:
            break

    return process

p = start_module()
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGALRM)
```

As far as I can see, using a thread or not to send the signal should not make any difference.  Notice that `os.kill` does not necessarily kill a process: it sends it a signal that the process can then handle appropriately (an `ALARM` signal, here).

---

If your intention was to pass some input to the process's `stdin`, then things are also easy.  You just need to add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to the `Popen` call and print to the `stdin` attribute of the new process:

```
def start_module():
    cmd = '%s/libraries/OpenBR' % settings.MODULES_DIR
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if line.find('Algorithm loaded') > -1:
            break

    return process

p = start_module()
print >> p.stdin, "Hello world!"
print >> p.stdin, "How are things there?"
```

Comment: Killing the process is not the purpose, rather to send a `stdin` to it. Basically sending a parameter and receiving the result. I believe I was unclear in my question but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PhilipMasek `os.kill` can be used to send arbitrary signals to the subprocess, not just kill it. You said you wanted to send a signal in your original question, though it sounds like maybe you actually want to write to the stdin of the subprocess?

Comment: Okey, I think I managed. But now I've got problems reading the output of the `stdin`. I tried this:
`process.stdin.write(image_directory)
 print process.stdout.readline()`
But the thread is just standing still on the print and not printing anything. I don't want to close the process. I just want the output after giving an `image_director`. I need to later be able to write to `stdin` again with another `image_directory` and retrieve the results from that.

Comment: I found my answer to my last question, I combined this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343917/1052393](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343917/1052393) with this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13605804/1052393](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13605804/1052393)

Althoug, I only get the first line from the stdout... Any clues?